# restrict key for indexer in typescript to only 1 value from a union

Tags: typescript

I want to specify that a dynamic object key can only be 1 value from a union:

```
export enum HTTPMethod {
  DELETE = 'DELETE',
  GET = 'GET',
  HEAD = 'HEAD',
  OTIONS = 'OPTIONS',
  PATCH = 'PATCH',
  POST = 'POST',
  PUT = 'PUT',
}

export type FetchData<TData> = (
  routeOrBody?: string | BodyInit | object,
  body?: BodyInit | object,
) => Promise<TData | undefined>

export type GraphqlFetch<TData> = (
  query: string,
  variables?: BodyInit | object,
) => Promise<TData>

export type AbortFetch = () => void

export interface FetchCommands<TData = any> {
  get: FetchData<TData>
  post: FetchData<TData>
  patch: FetchData<TData>
  put: FetchData<TData>
  del: FetchData<TData>
  delete: FetchData<TData>
  query: GraphqlFetch<TData>
  mutate: GraphqlFetch<TData>
  abort: AbortFetch
}

export interface UseFetchBaseResult<TData = any> {
  data: TData | undefined
  loading: boolean
  error: Error
}

export type RestFetchMethods =
  | 'get'
  | 'post'
  | 'patch'
  | 'put'
  | 'del'
  | 'delete'

export type GraphqlFetchMethods = 'query' | 'mutate'

export type FetchRequest<TData> = {
  [key in keyof FetchCommands<TData>]: key extends RestFetchMethods
    ? FetchData<TData>
    : key extends GraphqlFetchMethods
    ? GraphqlFetch<TData>
    : AbortFetch
}

export type DestructuringCommands<TData> = [
  TData | undefined,
  FetchCommands<TData>,
]

export type ObjectDestructure<
  TKey extends keyof FetchCommands,
  TData
> = UseFetchBaseResult<TData> & { [key: TKey]: FetchRequest<TData>[TKey] }
```

Specfifically it is this type:

```
export type ObjectDestructure<
  TKey extends keyof FetchCommands,
  TData
> = UseFetchBaseResult<TData> & { [key: TKey]: FetchRequest<TData>[TKey] }
```

I want Tkey to be 1 value from the union and not be a mapped type but `[key: TKey]` is erroring with

> An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.

[Here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwBIBUsAUCywMAFhACZwDeAsAFBxwAiAogDLNbNwC8cA5C3ac+AGjoMA4hx78pWUeMzMAgoxl8MKxgvpwA8lgCSegHIBldXtxHTZnQ1zKsAYQzrHLjPbi49ZrO5+8mK6uACqAbx84cF0AL50dKCQsHAwAJ5gwHAAYkQAxsSMAIYwxQA8WCVlAHwyABSKUBDIMMB6UABC5OkA-ABccADOMFAAlogA5nAAPnDdZOmGiGPwcxAARgBWwPkwIQwbPQPzPcurs3CbO3shAJQ8dbjNqGNDwJXVxZfIiGTAADMJsAyDVErRktB4BksnAJFBimBiABHAA2eRghU+pWKdV4jV0yOQwCg6UGI3GUwOcAAbsVxsUNqjgEMTgslis1ldtrt9nQHtwni83h8qjiwbQkuAoWlMtllEdYBjCg0BXUaRAxmRwZDUhM2lAAcV8tllcRnBBUKhin8htiyjIbek6jRdJMiIMzV97bjFJARp6CkUcT6JQwwKVCoHMcGyqG-a1o4VvWLaop-qik7GKqnfboM0RgFmU18w3AiSSyXCEUi0Wb47pUK1SkXq4iUeigw2GIyoYMFVCzfEddK9YgDUaTXAwu8zZ1iu8AEos5ComA+x2IZ1UdM4wa5n5-QHA7W6VEQYpkCaTQZHCDMm2KEnNKCDZhQF-DyUQ0fQuVwZcRjNQgSHIIYeEUOY+HdGA+Eg-h-Vg+C+AjGM4N0KCwFadCGCgjMcMuPgCzadCpRSP9YXhds6yDEDSDIcCogrUk+EIpsyhIkdyNlWEzWXCsRlDGRXQYABtABrYB0jgCY4Ek9IIABXIgwtK0bQY0MAF1BnkhAQDaW0AJZGBgKIeihkUBhemUmMS3FSy4B0qS9IMhi21rTsYzosCHOsqiPPrXMywYftFRMoMvzImUYWyRhjKgZA9mQSlJlU61bSE3hRMUA85l+f4gUQEFqTNNL1LtIKQk0rjov-PQeT2OKKUSmBko+HKAGlnNAVzwPkxSbMKMrbWpXM6DxadZyDeclxXNchIAMioOAJKk-cuvSbTBuIfjiUEoLRKwDbNLgBJaCAA) is a playground with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `[key in keyof TKey]` [solves your problem](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwBIBUsAUCywMAFhACZwDeAsAFBxwAiAogDLNbNwC8cA5C3ac+AGjoMA4hx78pWUeMzMAgoxl8MKxgvpwA8lgCSegHIBldXtxHTZnQ1zKsAYQzrHLjPbi49ZrO5+8mK6uACqAbx84cF0AL50dKCQsHAwAJ5gwHAAYkQAxsSMAIYwxQA8WCVlAHwyABSKUBDIMMB6UABC5OkA-ABccADOMFAAlogA5nAAPnDdZOmGiGPwcxAARgBWwPkwIQwbPQPzPcurs3CbO3shAJQ8dbjNqGNDwJXVxZfIiGTAADMJsAyDVErRktB4BksnAJFBimBiABHAA2eRghU+pWKdV4jV0yOQwCg6UGI3GUwOcAAbsVxsUNqjgEMTgslis1ldtrt9nQHtwni83h8qjiwbQkuAoWlMtllEdYBjCg0BXUaRAxmRwZDUhM2lAAcV8tllcRnBBUKhin8htiyjIbek6jRdJMiIMzV97bjFJARp6CkUcT6JQwwKVCoHMcGyqG-a1o4VvWLaop-qik7GKqnfboM0RgFmU18w3AiSSyXCEUi0Wb47pUK1SkXq4iUeigw2GIyoYMFVCzfEddK9YgDUaTXAwu8zZ1iu8AEos5ComA+x2IZ1UdM4wa5n5-QHA7W6VEQYpkCaTQZHCDMm2KEnNKCDZhQF-DyUQ0fQuVwZcRjNQgSHIIYeEUOY+HdGA+Eg-h-Vg+C+AjGM4N0KCwFadCGCgjMcMuPgCzadCpRSP9YXhds6yDEDSDIcCogrUk+EIpsyhIkdyNlWEzWXCsRlDGRXQYABtABrYB0jgCY4Ek9IIABXIgwtK0bQY0MAF1BnkhAQDaW0AJZGBgKIeihkUBhemUmMS3FSy4B0qS9IMhi21rTsYzosCHOsqiPPrXMywYftFRMoMvzImUYWyRhjKgZA9mQSlJlU61bSE3hRMUA85l+f4gUQEFqTNNL1LtIKQk0rjov-PQeT2OKKUSmBko+HKAGlnNAVzwPkxSbMKMrbWpXM6DxadZyDeclxXNchIAMioOAJOc2T+qUrAuvSbTBuIfjiUEoLRK2qTNLgBJaCAA).